# Postfix: внутренний список рассылки закрыть от сообщений извне

Tags: postfix, спам

Ситуация такая: есть унаследованный почтовый сервер на основе Postfix. У него также есть фильтр spamassassin. На этом сервере есть рассылка вида list@example.com, отправлять на которую можно только от @example.com. До недавнего времени так и было. Но тут однажды кто-то умный из Америки отправил якобы с этого адреса на несуществующий, и диагностическое письмо пришла всем подписчикам этого списка рассылки.

Нужно простое, но железное правило (или сочетание правил), которое для RCPT TO: list@example.com пропускает только с MAIL FROM: @example.com. Причём spamassassin лучше не использовать (ведь он не удаляет, а добавляет в сабж **** SPAM ****), т.к. это не только спам, а и нарушение маршрута, и надо сделать в рамках `/etc/postfix/main.cf`